# Typeahead not working for cyrillic

Tags: typeahead, cyrillic

I'm using Typeahead version 0.10.5. It's working for english words but it's not working for each word written in cyrrilic. Some words written in cyrillic are shown, but others aren't. What is this due to?

I'm using it like this:

```js
$('#edicode').typeahead({
            source: function(query, process){
                 CallAPI("GET", "/companies/get/" + query + "/like", function (data) {
                   
                    var sourcedata = new Array();
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

                    var count = 0;
                    $.each(jsonData, function(jsonId) {
                       
                            sourcedata.push(jsonData[jsonId].CODE +  ' / ' + jsonData[jsonId].NAME);
                            selectedItems[jsonData[jsonId].CODE] = JSON.stringify(jsonData[jsonId]);
                            count++;
                    });
                    if(count <= 0)
                    {
                        $('#company_name').val('');
                        $('#company_name').prop('readonly', false);
                    }
     console.log(sourcedata);
                    return process(sourcedata);
                });
            },
            updater: function (item) {
                var info = item.split(" / ");
                var company = jQuery.parseJSON(selectedItems[info[0]]);
                
                $('#EDICode').val(company.CODE);
                
                return  company.CODE +  '/ ' + company.NAME ;
            },
            name: 'Company',
            displayKey: 'value',
   minLength: 2,
   maxItem: 15,
   accent: true,
   hint: true
        }).blur(function(){

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Took 1 hour to find:
open bootstrap-typeahead.js (not minified)
find:

```
    matcher: function (item) {
    return ~item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());
    },
```

change to:

```
    matcher: function (item) {

    var x=item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase());;
    if(x==-1)
        x=0;
    return ~x
    },
```